# TreeNode SelectNodeChanged Event c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Problem:
I have 5 nodes in Treeview list including child nodes. Whenever I select one node it should display the name of the node in the combo box automatically without the need of pressing a button.

When I use ONselectednodechanged event it only fires once. So when I click on the node for the first time it fires the event but it does not do anything after that.

Could someone please give me some suggestions on what to do. I want it to automatically display the name of the node in the combo box when I click on it.

c#, ASP.net

Here is what I wrote so far:

```
protected void nav_tree_items_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
            if (nav_view_add.Visible == true)
            {
                panel_helper.GroupingText = "Add";
                nav_multi.SetActiveView(nav_view_add); //set active view
                nav_btn_save_add.CausesValidation = true;

                DataRow[] row1 = TableClass.MainTable.Select("ItemId = " + nav_tree_items.SelectedValue);
                nav_dd_parent.SelectedValue = row1[0]["ItemId"].ToString().Trim();

            }
```

When the program is executed it does not even make the panel visible.

```
<asp:TreeView ID="nav_tree_items" runat="server" Height="100%" ShowLines="True" 
                                    Width="123%" onselectednodechanged="nav_tree_items_SelectedNodeChanged">
                                    <HoverNodeStyle CssClass="hoverTreeItem" />
```

Answer (score 2):

When I work with TreeView, I use the "AfterSelect" event. The stub can be easily generated by double clicking the TreeView control in [Design] mode. You can then do something like the following, using the data however you wish (MessageBox is just an example).

```
    private void naviTree_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The node you just selected is [" + e.Node.ToString() + "]");
    }
```

Hope this helps at all.

Comment: I am using SYSTem.Web.UI.Webcontrols as a refrence... I tried using System.Windows.Forms but it does not work...